# Best way to schedule CPU limiting

Tags: windows-10, cpu-speed

What's the best way to schedule a limit to CPU speed so my computer's fan doesn't wake me up at night?

It looks like it might be possible to schedule calls to `powercfg.exe`, e.g.

```
powercfg.exe -setacvalueindex SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMAX 50
powercfg.exe -setactive SCHEME_CURRENT
```

but I just found that command on a [forum post](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=13916) and I'm not sure I entirely understand what it does.  Also I'm not sure how to schedule the command execution, other than via `cron` in WSL, which I suspect wouldn't work because it wouldn't have administrator privilege.

Does Windows have a feature that does this in a more robust way?  Is there a free application that will do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this using Task Scheduler (just type "Task Scheduler" into the Search box on the taskbar).  I set up a task to run a batch file (`Scripts\proczero.bat` in my home directory) at 10 PM every day.  The batch file just contains these two commands:

```
powercfg.exe -setacvalueindex SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMAX 0
powercfg.exe -setactive SCHEME_CURRENT
```

I also made another, nearly identical batch file that I run from the command line to conveniently re-engage full power:

```
powercfg.exe -setacvalueindex SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMAX 100
powercfg.exe -setactive SCHEME_CURRENT
```

I just run it if I'm doing something particularly processor-intensive—most stuff runs fine even with the CPU operating at its lowest frequency.  It's equivalent to changing the maximum processor state in *Settings -> System -> Power & sleep -> etc.* but involves a lot less clicking.

This solution works well except that the current window appears to lose focus when the batch file is run, which can be a problem if I'm playing a game that doesn't deal well with losing focus.  But, of course, I would never be doing that at bedtime anyway.

Another issue is that the batch file as written will cease to work if I change the power scheme.  I suspect that replacing `SCHEME_BALANCED` with `SCHEME_CURRENT` would remedy this, but I have insufficient interest in changing my power scheme to test that theory.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method is to open
*Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings >
Processor power management > Maximum processor state*.

Change the setting that you use to less than 100%.
A small change can be very effective and you may not notice the difference,
such as 97%. Reduce more if required.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the main effect of small amounts below 100% is (typically) to disable Turbo Boost and that this advice may adversely affect general performance though the main loss will be with more "burst" tasks. https://www.tautvidas.com/blog/2011/04/disabling-intel-turbo-boost/  This is more of a "permanent" change rather than the time based change requested.

Comment: You might ask yourself what is happening in idle periods. My Desktop computer is on 7x24 and the fan does not run when idle. I have an older Laptop running Windows Insider and it is often on overnight and the fan does not run. Check Admin Tools, Resource Monitor and let if run for an hour or so. What is taking all the CPU?

Comment: @John Letting it run for an hour wouldn't necessarily tell me anything.  The issue is that anything that happens over an 8-10 hour window is liable to wake me up, and even if this only happens once a month, it's too much.

Comment: What wakes it up? You may use `powercfg /lastwake` to find.

Comment: @harrymc It runs all night doing downloads.  My internet connection really sucks so that's the only way I can acquire media.

Comment: So it's not asleep at all, just working slowly. Did you get to see if it's doing anything special when it acting up? Checked the temperature? Internet connection working? Windows Update perhaps updating? Did my above advice help?

Comment: And does it always happen at about the same time?

Comment: @harrymc No, I tried to go back to sleep :)  I'm sure there are about a million reasons why it would need to spin up to 100% CPU briefly overnight and I'm not about to try to pin every one down and get woken up each time I discover that I didn't get them all yet.

Comment: Try perhaps to set the Maximum processor state to a low setting which is enough for downloading but not much more, even maybe 50%.